# Verizon HTC Incredible 2

Tags: sim-unlocking, carriers

Will rooting my HTC Incredible 2 allow me to switch carriers ? If not does anyone have any information on how to unlock my phone from Verizon ??

Answer (score 0):

CDMA carriers tend to not allow phones from other carriers to operate on their networks. There is not a way to get your Incredible 2 to operate on another network. Rooting your phone will have no affect on this.

Per [This link](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2407896,00.asp), here is an explanation:

> **What CDMA vs. GSM Means to You**
>
> For call quality, the technology you
>   use is much less important than the way your carrier has built its
>   network. There are good and bad CDMA and GSM networks, but there are
>   key differences between the technologies. Here's what you, as a
>   consumer, need to know.
>
> It's much easier to swap phones on GSM networks, because GSM carriers
>   put customer information on a removable SIM card. Take the card out,
>   put it in a different phone, and the new phone now has your number.
>   What's more, to be considered GSM, a carrier must accept any
>   GSM-compliant phone. So the GSM carriers don't have total control of
>   the phone you're using.
>
> That's not the case with CDMA. In the U.S., CDMA carriers use
>   network-based white lists to verify their subscribers. That means you
>   can only switch phones with your carrier's permission, and a carrier
>   doesn't have to accept any particular phone onto its network. It
>   could, but typically, U.S. carriers choose not to.
>
> In other words, you can take an unlocked AT&T phone over to T-Mobile
>   (although its 3G may not work well because the frequency bands are
>   different). You can't take a Verizon phone over to Sprint, because
>   Sprint's network rejects non-Sprint phones.